Chess Tournament Probability Question.
Question: A chess tournament has 128 players, each with a distinct rating. Assume that the player with the higher rating always wins against a lower rated opponent and that the winner proceeds to the subsequent round. What is the probability that the highest rated and second-highest rated players will meet in the final?
I am calculating it like this:
P(Player 1 & NOT Player 2 in Round 1) = 126/127
P(Player 1 & NOT Player 2 in Round 2) = 62/63
P(Player 1 & NOT Player 2 in Round 3) = 30/31
P(Player 1 & NOT Player 2 in Round 4) = 14/15
P(Player 1 & NOT Player 2 in Round 5) = 6/7
P(Player 1 & NOT Player 2 in Round 6) = 2/3

Therefore P(Player 1 and Player 2 in Round 7) = 
126/127 * 62/63 * 30/31 * 14/15 * 6/7 * 2/3 = 0.5039

Is this correct? When I look it up online they say the answer is 0.000062?

Your answer is correct.  Each finalist comes from a group of 64, and the problem reduces to the probability of them being in different sets of 64.  This is 64 divided by 127, which is your answer.

Where have you seen online that the answer is that low number? If I understand the question correctly, the desired probability should just be equal to the probability that the top two players are in opposite halves of the draw, which should be $64/127 \approx 0.504$, as you've determined.

Thank you very much. Websites like quantguide.io are a scam then. The other source was: https://brainly.com/question/39297633 which says it's 0.000062.

When I enter 0.504 into the answer field here, it says it's wrong: https://www.quantguide.io/questions/chess-tournament-i

Whether either go so far as to qualify as "scams" might be debatable, both both are certainly bunk and provably wrong in at least this case.  In fact, most similar websites that are plainly apparent to be "for profit first and foremost" are not made by experts like they claim and will have regular mistakes like this and are generally not worth anyone's time.

@THAT_AI_GUY Entering the answer "64/127" is accepted on the link you mentioned

Just tried it, thank you! Strange they don't accept decimal answers!
